# 1st table Row matching in 2nd table Column Name and SELECT Column data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table like this :

table 1st :

```
   ID    Varible_Name   
     1    abc            
     1    pqr            
     1    xyz
```

I need this way.
table 2nd :

```
  ID    abc   pqr  xyz  
     1    235   345  567
     2     456   788  090
     3     567   454  908
```

Comment: i am trying PIVOT fun but it is not working proper.

Comment: Please fix your data sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a dynamic `PIVOT` like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
    ([ID] int, [Varible_Name] varchar(3), amount int)


INSERT INTO #TempTable
    ([ID], [Varible_Name],amount)
VALUES
    (1, 'abc',235),
    (1, 'pqr',345),
    (1, 'xyz',567),
    (2, 'abc',456),
    (2, 'pqr',788),
    (2, 'xyz',090),
    (3, 'abc',567),
    (3, 'pqr',454),
    (3, 'xyz',908)



DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME([Varible_Name]) 
                    from #TempTable
                    group by [Varible_Name]
                    order by [Varible_Name]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT [ID],' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select [ID], [Varible_Name], [amount]
                from #TempTable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum([amount])
                for [Varible_Name] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query);
```

**Result:**

```
 ID   abc  pqr  xyz
  1   235  345  567
  2   456  788  90
  3   567  454  908
```

**Note:** If you want to save the result set to a temp table, you can make use of `INTO` table and modify the `@query` like

```
set @query = 'SELECT [ID],' + @cols + 'into ##TempTbl2 from 
             (
                select [ID], [Varible_Name], [amount]
                from #TempTable
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                sum([amount])
                for [Varible_Name] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

 select * from ##TempTbl2
```

[image]

Comment: working good but jibin is it possible to 235 / x value * 100, 456  / x value * 100,567  / x value * 100...etc.
and this answer store to the another table.

Comment: @amit I didn't get your 1st point and for the second issue you can use the `INTO` table and  modify the `@query` to `SELECT [ID],' + @cols + ' into ##TempTbl2 from`. For retrieving the values use `select * from ##TempTbl2 `

Comment: @jabin : Error to the  Invalid object name '##TempTbl2'.

Comment: @jabin : Thank you very much...its work proper..done :)

Comment: @jabin : is it possible to each cell multiply by 100 and storted o the ##TempTbl2..??